# How to fix - Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds] - on Spark Shell - WIndows 7 Professional

Tags: shell, apache-spark

Running Spark-shell from command line ( windows 7.0 professional )
same error happens on Spark 1.5.2 and Spark 1.5.0 and Spark 1.4.1

** Seems like something wrong with my machine definitely - any pointers

I tried this -  -Dspark.akka.timeout=30000

However this did not fix the issue

I have scale 2.10.3 on my machine

Stack Trace

```
15/11/28 16:17:32 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/11/28 16:17:32 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/11/28 16:17:42 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
        at akka.remote.Remoting.start(Remoting.scala:180)
        at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:184)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:618)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:615)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:615)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:632)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:141)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1991)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1982)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnvFactory.create(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:424)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
        at $line3.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:9)
        at $line3.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:18)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:20)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:24)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.<init>(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:157)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:664)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
15/11/28 16:17:42 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
15/11/28 16:17:42 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
15/11/28 16:17:42 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
        at akka.remote.Remoting.start(Remoting.scala:180)
        at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:184)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:618)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:615)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:615)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:632)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:141)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1991)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1982)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnvFactory.create(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:424)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:9)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:18)
        at <init>(<console>:20)
        at .<init>(<console>:24)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:157)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:664)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:193)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSQLContext(SparkILoop.scala:1028)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:9)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:18)
        at <init>(<console>:20)
        at .<init>(<console>:24)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:157)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:664)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

15/11/28 16:17:45 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
<console>:10: error: not found: value sqlContext
```

Comment: Having same issue.. did u find any solution? I am running spark on a local mode. In my case, The project was running properly before. But after setting up new environment I am getting this error in eclipse's console while execute the related project file. It would be great if u can suggest something. Thanxx..

Comment: Anyone knows how to resolve this? We have a very similar issue

Comment: @Parth Vishvajit what is the eclipse version you are using?

Comment: @poohdedoo I am using eclipse Mars 1. we found out that the issue was using `.cache()` method. we were performing some operations (both transformation and actions) on 2 dataframes(which was created and immediately cache using `.cahce()`). after that we were trying to perform `join`  on 2 derived dataframe, but at that point this problem was occurring `futures timed out after 300 seconds` , we removed `.cache()` which we used with the initially created dataframe and after that its working normally. you can also try it by removing `cache()` if you are using it in your code.

Comment: Thankss @ParthVishvajit

Comment: did this solve your problem?

Comment: @ParthVishvajit - any idea why removing .cache() resolved this? I would really like to reuse my initial DF since it's read from a remote HDFS cluster, removing .cache() will degrade performance due to recomputation.